# how to increase my Left Join query performance in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, select, left-join

I inherited a site running Coldfusion8 and MySQL 5.0.88.

I have two tables - articles (**A**), which contains product info, and pricelists (**P**) which includes seller pricelists.

Products are unique in the products table but may contain multiple entries in the pricelist table (depending on number of pricelists).

In my product search, I need to get the product info from **A** and if the user is assigned a pricelist by the seller, I need to also grab the price from the respective pricelist in **P**.

I'm pre-compiling all sellerIDs and pricelist names before doing my actual product query, which looks like this:

```
SELECT count(A.id) AS total
    FROM arts A

    <cfif variables.use_pricelists neq "">  
    LEFT JOIN preislisten p ON
            A.ean = P.ean
        AND A.sellerID = p.sellerID
        AND (
            // precompiled list - hardcoded loop
            ( P.list_name = "-Standard-" AND P.sellerID = "2222222222222" )
            OR
            ( P.list_name = "I" AND P.sellerID = "3333333333333" )
            )
    </cfif>
    WHERE
    ...
```

While this works... it takes forever. Without checking for pricelists I can run my search in less than 1sec. If pricelists need to checked, it takes 7-10 secs.

**Question**:
Can this be done faster with a different type of Syntax?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you index your columns, for better performance
Create index syntax:

create index idx_ean on preislisten (ean)

Comment: I'm still in my first month with MySQL. Do you have a good starting point for indexing?

Comment: Please create indexes on the columns which you are considering for the join, The create syntax syntax is shown above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Quick question: Does the indexed field need to be unique? ean will be unique in A but can have multiple entries in P